# Linearizing a nonlinear system of ODE about an equilibrium

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, solution-verification

> Since the method below is probably correct, and correctness is potentially irrelevant to my ability to do what I want to learn. Assume below is correct. $\def\b{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\e{\end{pmatrix}}\def\1{y_1}\def\2{y_2}\def\R{\Rightarrow}\def\l{\lambda}\def\le{\left}\def\ri{\right}$
>
> $\dot{y}= \b 3\1+\1\2 \\ \1+\2 -\2^2 \e$

This occurs when $\dot{y}=0$.

Converting $\dot{y}$ to a nicer form:

$\dot{y}= Ay+u$, where $A = \b 3 & \1 \\ 1&1\e, u = \b 0\\-\2^2 \e$

No such nicer form apparently.

So now I just 'go it': 
$$3\1+\1\2=0\;\;(1)$$
$$\1+\2-\2^2=0\;\;(2)$$

$$(1)\R \1(3+\2)=0, \1=0 \text{ or } \2 = -3$$
$$(2)\R \1=\2(\2-1)$$

Hence we have: $(0,0),(0,1),(12,-3)$

Now I believe I take the eigenvectors of $A$ given these $\1$.

$\1=0,\;\;\det\le| A \ri| = \det\le|\b 3-\l &0\\1&1-\l\e\ri|=(3-\l)(1-\l)\R\l=1,3$

Which is an unstable improper node.

$\1=12,\;\;\det\le| A \ri| = \det\le|\b 3-\l &12\\1&1-\l\e\ri|=(3-\l)(1-\l) -12\R 3 -3\l-\l+\l^2=0\R\l^2-4\l+3\R\l=-3,-1$

This is a stable improper node at both $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

> How do I derive the linear system about each critical point: $(0,0),(0,1),(12,-3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearization of a system $\dot y=F(y)$ around an equilibrium $y_*$ is
$$\dot y = F'(y_*)(y-y_*)\tag1$$
where $F'$ is a square matrix (Jacobian).
This is based on the fact that $F(y)\approx F'(y_*)(y-y_*)$ neat $y_*$. It is convenient to let $z=y-y_*$, thus rewriting (1) as 
$$\dot z = F'(y_*)z\tag2$$
which is  a linear system.

In your case
$$F(y)  = \begin{pmatrix} 3y_1+y_1y_2 \\ y_1+y_2 -y_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
hence
$$F'(y)  = \begin{pmatrix} 3+y_2 &  y_1  \\ 1 & 1- 2y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Plug in the equilibrium point and you get linear system, the stability of which can be studied by looking at the eigenvalues of $F'(y_*)$.

> Now I believe I take the eigenvectors of $A$

No, you take the eigenvalues of $F'(y_*)$. Only at the zero equilibrium these are the same thing. At other equilibria, $-y_2^2$ has nonzero derivative and therefore contributes to the linearized system.